# Is it possible to use Shared Worker across subdomains?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, shared-worker

I have two sub-domains:
one.example.com 
two.example.com

When I use Shared Worker (served from one.example.com/sharedworker.js & two.example.com/sharedworker.js), will both the domains have access to the same SharedWorkerGlobalScope?

If not, is it possible to somehow have a shared storage on the client side, across sub-domains apart from using cookies?

Comment: Do they exist on the same server?

Comment: No time right now, but the first thing I would try would be to set both your documents domains the same (`document.domain = "example.com"`), though I doubt that would work... IIRC Storage didn't work like that, neither do BroadCastChannels, but I may be wrong.